# Pass reference of this inside object react+redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Below is my code snippet

```
 const slipSource = {
    endDrag(props, monitor) {
       const item = monitor.getItem();
       const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
       this.props.updateSelections(selections)
  }
 };
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
          updateSelections: (selections) => {
          dispatch(updateSelections(selections)) }
      }
 }
```

Here n this code I am calling updateSelections() method inside slipSource  obj.
but my method is not getting reference of "this" inside obj, cause endDrag() function is inside obj context.

How to get reference of "this" inside endDrag() function.

Comment: endDrag receive another arg `endDrag(props, monitor, component)`, you can use component as this, not sure if component.props will work, docs : http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html

Comment: @YanMayatskiy 
I am calling it  component.dispatchProps.updateSelections(selections)
is it correct.

Comment: @YanMayatskiy, yes, component.props would work as expected.

Comment: actually i am getting method in dispatchProps not in props

Comment: @KalashriAundhkar - well, i really didn't touch react for couple of months, but props should contain the dispatched props as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
endDrag(props, monitor, component){}
```

The `component` argument is behaving as `this`, so `component.props` should work same as `this.props`.

from docs: http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html

example code to component argument: https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/03%20Nesting/Drop%20Targets/Dustbin.js

```
drop(props, monitor, component) {
    ...
    component.setState({
      ...
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am calling  component.props.updateSelections(selections)
inside the endDrag() function . getting below error 
main-2dd52dc….js:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: updateSelections is not defined(…)

Comment: you can't access only this function from connect? or other props as well?

Comment: have you tried using the props argument  `props.updateSelections(selections)`?